# pass along 1 instance of array in array

Tags: ios, swift

```
var countries = ["American", "Asian", "Italian"]
var items = [["Mcdonalds", "BurgerKing", "Big Boy"], ["PFChangs", "China One Buffet"], ["Pizza House", "Pizza Hit", "Olive Garden", "Maggianos"]]
if (segue.identifier == "segueone")
{
    let cellIndexPath = self.tableView!.indexPathForCell(sender as         UITableViewCell)
    if  let unwrappedCellindexPath = cellIndexPath
{
var nextVC = (segue.destinationViewController as TableTwo)
    nextVC.items = items[unwrappedCellindexPath.row]
}
}
}
```

and on the second table controller I have

```
var items: [String]?
```

So with this code, I am able to find the index path of of my first table containing the items in the country array.  with this index path, I am able to set that index path to the appropriate array within the items array.  However, I am having a difficult time understanding how to pass along only one instance within my items double array.

so. two questions.  How would i go about setting up an item in my third controller to reflect an individual item being transferred from my items array?

```
 "var item = [items]?"?
```

secondly, how would i go about setting up the double index path needed to pass an individual item?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, but a dictionary might simplify some of this.  `let items = ["American":["McDonalds","Burger King","Big Boy"],"Asian":["PF Changs"]]` etc...

Comment: what are the benefits of using a dictionary vs my current method?  also, how would i go about selecting an individual item in a given dictionary? (still going back to selecting one)

Comment: how would i go about sending a specific key in a dictionary to a new controller?

Comment: I already answered this question in a comment to your last question. You have a simple array, items in your second controller. When the user selects a row, you just pass items[indexPath.row]; That will pass a single restaurant to the third controller.

Comment: I had problems with it and didn't receive a reply, so i was looking for more help.  Do you mind taking a look?  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yiqrymrrtlda1a5/AACzRtM4RLy6dT5Ksf3JRYeJa?dl=0            I was also wondering, if i didn't set up the the IBOoutlet, would i still leave the "if let" in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information. Do you have a sectioned table view then, where the sections are cuisines, and the rows within the section are restaurants examples of that cuisine?

Or is your top-level table view just cuisines?

You mention a third view controller. Do you have 3 levels of master/detail?

- Top level = cuisines.
- 2'nd level = restaurants from that cuisine.
- 3'rd level menu for the restaurant (or something)

It looks like you'r passing an array of restaurants for a given cuisine to the second-level view controller, which is fine. Then, in that second view controller, if the user picks a cell, you'd select whatever detail is appropriate for that restaurant and pass that to the third level.

I'm guessing here however. You need to explain more clearly what you're trying to do so we can better help you.

Comment: you are correct with your assumption.  Cuisine, to restaurants of that cuisine, and then specific information about that restaurant.

Comment: top level has both cuisines and restaurants.  when a user selects a cell in the first table (first controller), the appropriate index path is found, and then the proper array in the items array is pushed to the second controller.    when a user selects one of the restaurants in the second controller, that specific instance is pushed to the third controller to be displayed.  I am unsure of how to send over the index path of the index path of my items array.